# Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I`m loading Spark using intellij project without an installed Spark.

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
```

I`ve added com.spark.databricks.xml to spark by using

```
sparkConf.set("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:/.../spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar")
sparkConf.setExecutorEnv("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "C:/.../spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar")
sparkConf.set("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "C:/.../spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar")
sparkConf.setExecutorEnv("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "C:/.../spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar")
sparkConf.setJars(Array("C:/.../spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar"    ))
```

and with

```
spark.sparkContext.addJar("C:/.../spark-xml_2.10-0.2.0.jar")
```

but when trying to use `spark.read.format ("com.databricks.spark.xml")` I get the exception "Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.xml. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html".

How do I fix this? I know it is recommended to add jars using spark-shell but I do not have a spark-shell as I do`nt have spark installed...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a project with maven/sbt you can add the spark-xml dependency as mentioned below:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-xml_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>0.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Ref: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-xml_2.11/0.4.1

Comment: Yes I have it in my maven. I think the jar needs to be added to SparkContext itself, and maven/sbt only add it to my project